# Python Selenium : How to stop Auto Refreshing of Internal Elements of a Webpage in Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I want to automate mail checking on `temp-mail.org`
But the problem is the page keeps on refreshing internal components of page and therefore Selenium can't target mail.

My code:

```
mail= browser.find_element_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[@title="__mail title__"]')

mail.click()
```

But there is no response.
Then I noticed that contents of page are auto refreshing internally.

So how to stop this auto refreshing?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_

Comment: That's the problem I have no knowledge of JavaScript so can't figure out :-(

Comment: If you were to print mail you should get the source code of that element. I would say after that use beautifulsoup (html parser) to store and check for whatever values you want.

Comment: @divyanshch I want to create a dynamic solution so Beautiful Soup won't work.

Comment: I think you can dynamically load the page then get the source code using selenium ‘driver.page_source’. Then pass that into selenium to easily find the element you are looking for. This way you are using bs4 to parse and selenium to get new fresh data. In this method you are pretty much taking a snapshot of whatever you see on your screen once things load and doing your processing of emails on it there. Hope this helps and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 0):

How about stopping the script aftre 3/5 secs of its runtime.

Try this :

```
fire = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fire.set_preference("http.response.timeout", 3)
fire.set_preference("dom.max_script_run_time", 3)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fire)

driver.get("url")
```

Comment: How can I add this preferences to chromedriver?

Comment: @user8810517 i have no clue on how to add this argument to chromedriver. Better use firefox driver as it has better documentation.